How could we encourage the use of screenshots/ screen recordings in ux.stackexchange.com?
Discussions in ux.stackexchange.com, naturally, deal with issues about visual representation and when they come without any screenshots/ screen recordings, this automatically leads to poor quality.
(I think, the audience here could easily figure out why trying to describe a visual UI issue in words, is cumbersome (to both readers and posters). The chances for confusion/ misunderstanding/ tiresome explanations/ etc, soar up.)
While screenshots are being employed in ux.stackexchange.com, that is by far not the most common practice. As far as screen recordings are concerned, I have never seen any of that used.
Any ideas how the platform could facilitate and encourage the use of visuals in UX-related questions?

Increases explanation freedom ! Interesting
